# C++ OOP segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a task at the college. I'm making a chess board with chess pieces on it. I have a method `step()` to move them. But I need to print the result of the move. I get a segmentation fault after trying to print it. And are there any other methods to declare that chess board with symbols. It seems to me it is not properly declared. (Yes, chess pieces should be like `"01""10"`. I will use that later to make rules for each piece type).

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#define n 8
using namespace std;

int convert(char c) {
  if(c=='a')
    return 0;
  else if(c=='b')
    return 1;
  else if(c=='c')
    return 2;
  else if(c=='d')
    return 3;
  else if(c=='e')
    return 4;
  else if(c=='f')
    return 5;
  else if(c=='g')
    return 6;
  else 
    return 7;
}

class chess {
private:
  string board[n][n]= {{"02","03","04","06","05","04","03","02"}, //chessboard
                      {"01","01","01","01","01","01","01","01"}, //black
                      {"00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00"},
                      {"00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00"},
                      {"00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00"}, //00-empty cells
                      {"00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00"},
                      {"11","11","11","11","11","11","11","11"}, //white
                      {"12","13","14","16","15","14","13","12"}};
  public:
  chess() {}

  void print() {
    cout<<"  _";  //board marking
    for (int i='a'; i<='h'; i++)
      printf("_%c_",i);

    cout<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) { 
      printf("%d| ", i+1); //board marking
      for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        printf("%.2s ",board[i][j].c_str()); //print chess pieces
      }
      cout<<'\n';
    }
    cout<<'\n';
  }

  void step() { //move on another cell
    char figc, fign, cellc, celln;
    cout<<"Piece, char: "; //choose a chess piece
    cin>>figc;
    cout<<"Piece, num: ";
    cin>>fign;
    cout<<"Step, char: "; //move on cell - ...
    cin>>cellc;
    cout<<"Step, num: ";
    cin>>celln;
    board[celln-1][convert(celln)]=board[fign-1][convert(fign)];
    board[fign-1][convert(fign)]="00";
  }
};

int main() {
  chess A;
  A.step();
  A.print();
  return 0;
}
```

[Example. Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN9Gw.jpg)

Comment: `fign` and `celln` should be declared as `int`, instead of `char`

Comment: There is no OOP here. And very little C++ at all

Comment: please use tags for topics that are specific to the question. You also dont tag `function`, `if-statement`, `private` etc, just because your code uses them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiling your code with

```
g++ -g -faddress=sanitize main.cpp
```

Shows the following output:

```
    #0 0x7fdc8e7c4b40 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0x124b40)
    #1 0x7fdc8e7c4f18 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0x124f18)
    #2 0x56310c7ad092 in chess::step() /z/bob.cpp:65
    #3 0x56310c7a9c10 in main /z/bob.cpp:72
    #4 0x7fdc8e0b8b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #5 0x56310c7a9a19 in _start (/z/a.out+0x1a19)
```

Line 65 is:

```
board[fign-1][convert(fign)]="00";
```

in which we see `fign`, which is a `char` used as an integer.

Since the ascii range of letters and numbers is somewhere in the range 48-122, this exceeds the size of your array.

Using

```
board.at(fign-1).at(convert(fign))="00";
```

would have told you this immediately because `.at()` does bounds checking.

Answer (score 0):

- You Should have `fign & celln` datatype as `int.`
- And Also you need to have some condition, that check the input chars
  (a-z), and also the number is `< n` .

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string>
  #define n 8
  using namespace std;

  int convert(char c) {
    if(c=='a')
      return 0;
    else if(c=='b')
      return 1;
    else if(c=='c')
      return 2;
    else if(c=='d')
      return 3;
    else if(c=='e')
      return 4;
    else if(c=='f')
      return 5;
    else if(c=='g')
      return 6;
    else 
      return 7;
  }

  class chess {
  private:
    string board[n][n]= {{"02","03","04","06","05","04","03","02"}, //chessboard
                        {"01","01","01","01","01","01","01","01"}, //black
                        {"00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00"},
                        {"00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00"},
                        {"00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00"}, //00-empty cells
                        {"00","00","00","00","00","00","00","00"},
                        {"11","11","11","11","11","11","11","11"}, //white
                        {"12","13","14","16","15","14","13","12"}};
    public:
    chess() {}

    void print() {
      cout<<"  _";  //board marking
      for (int i='a'; i<='h'; i++)
        printf("_%c_",i);

      cout<<endl;
      for (int i=0; i<n; i++) { 
        printf("%d| ", i+1); //board marking
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
          printf("%.2s ",board[i][j].c_str()); //print chess pieces
        }
        cout<<'\n';
      }
      cout<<'\n';
    }

    void step() { //move on another cell
      char cellc, figc;
      int fign,celln; //change datatype as int
      cout<<"Piece, char: "; //choose a chess piece
      cin>>figc;
      cout<<"Piece, num: ";
      cin>>fign;
      cout<<"Step, char: "; //move on cell - ...
      cin>>cellc;
      cout<<"Step, num: ";
      cin>>celln;

      // cout<<"print=>"<<convert(cellc)<<endl;
      // cout<<celln-1<<"  "<<convert(cellc)<<endl;
      // cout<<fign-1<<"  "<<convert(figc)<<endl;
      // cout<<board[celln-1][convert(cellc)].c_str();
      // cout<<board[fign-1][convert(figc)].c_str();
      board[celln-1][convert(cellc)]=board[fign-1][convert(figc)];

      board[fign-1][convert(figc)]="00";
    }
  };
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score -2):

You're using a char fign and doing -1 on it.

Better to use atoi in this case --

```
    board[atoi(&fign)-1][convert(fign)]="00";
```

Outputs --

```
  __a__b__c__d__e__f__g__h_
1| 02 03 04 06 05 04 03 02
2| 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
3| 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
4| 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
5| 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
6| 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
7| 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 00
8| 12 13 14 16 15 14 13 12
```

Why you should not perform char-int?

Well, I added a printf %d on that one, gave me this, which is quite self-explanatory.

```
.
printf ("\nThe result of bad operation : %d\n", fign - 1);
.
.
The result of bad operation : 54
```

Comment: `atoi(&fign)` has undefined behaviour, since `atoi()` assumes it receives a nul terminated string.

Comment: `atoi` is an unsafe C function. In C++ land it is better to use [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: Peter and Richard, thanks for the inputs :) Would it be safe if we purposefully create a null terminated char[] and then pass it to the function? Rather, how about `(fign - '0') -1` instead of atoi?